# magento custom dashboard tabbed contents

Tags: php, xml, magento

I would like to create my own "grids" similar to magento's dashboard grids (bestsellers, most viewed products..).

I have tried copying the entire app/code/core/adminhtml folder to my local folder in the hopes of replicating the dashboard page, but magento can't find the page.

There's a better approach to this and I am hoping anyone could provide me the solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Tutoring a Software Product named Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite this method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Grids::_prepareLayout`.
[Here is a small and useful tutorial](http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/) on how to do it.
You can add a new tab similar to the ones that already exist

```
$this->addTab('reviewed_products', array(//tab name...mut be unique.
    'label'     => $this->__('Most Viewed Products'), //tab label
    'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/productsViewed', array('_current'=>true)),//url for ajax call
    'class'     => 'ajax'
));
```

And you can see how the grid is shown in this method `Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController::productsViewedAction()`
You can also see how the layout looks in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml` :

```
<adminhtml_dashboard_productsviewed>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/dashboard_tab_products_viewed" name="adminhtml.dashboard.tab.products.viewed"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_dashboard_productsviewed>
```